# Proper Fourier transform in Python?

Tags: python, fft, chemistry

I have signal data as a function of time and want to do fft in python.
[image]

I tried fft as shown below:

```
fs = 5000   # time interval of my data
fft = np.fft.fft(SIGNAL) / len(SIGNAL)  
fft_magnitude = abs(fft)
f = np.linspace(-(fs/2),fs/2,len(SIGNAL))
plt.stem(f, np.fft.fftshift(fft_magnitude))
```

This is what I got.  Anyone can help why only few peaks appear?
[image]

Comment: A peak at zero just corresponds to the fact that the mean (average) value of the signal is non-zero. What do the other peaks look like?

Comment: In general, when the fft consists of only a few peaks, that means that your signal is well approximated with a sum of just a few sine functions

Comment: It might be useful to see what `plt.stem(f[n1:n2], np.fft.fftshift(fft_magnitude)[n1:n2])` looks like, after you set `n1 = int(.45*len(SIGNAL))` and `n2 = int(.55*len(SIGNAL))`